# How to turn off build number overlay on Xcode app icon

Tags: xcode

Someone once tweeted a `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode` command to turn on an overlay on the Xcode app icon that shows the build number.

[image: Xcode app icon + build number overlay]

I want to turn it off now, but… I forgot the name of the defaults key. Does anyone here know what the key is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created a folder named `AppleInternal` inside your root directory. Type

```
sudo rm -rf /AppleInternal
```

to Terminal to remove it.

Answer (score 5):

For me this helped:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ShowDVTDebugMenu NO
```